# Cuda C threads synchronization with printf or other functions

Tags: cuda, printf

I have a problem with threads' id during the block executes. [image]
I would like to have sentence like :"My temporary string is printed via GPU!" as you see (on the attached photo ealier) the sentence has been displayed wrongly and I don't know how to fix it.

Code:

```
__global__ void Print(const char* const __string, const size_t* const loop_repeat)
{ 
    int id_x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    while (id_x < static_cast<int>(*loop_repeat))
    {
        printf("%c", __string[id_x]);
        __syncthreads();
        id_x += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* my_string = "My temporary string is printed via GPU!";
    size_t temp{};
    temp = Get_String_Length(my_string);    //get the string length
    //GPU MEMORY ALLOCATION
    size_t* my_string_length{};
    cudaMalloc((void**)&my_string_length, sizeof(size_t));
    //COPY VALUE FROM CPU(RAM) TO GPU
    cudaMemcpy(my_string_length, &temp, sizeof(size_t), HostToDevice);
    char* string_GPU{};
    cudaMalloc((void**)&string_GPU, (temp) * sizeof(char));
    //COPY VALUE FROM CPU(RAM) TO GPU
    cudaMemcpy(string_GPU, my_string, (temp) * sizeof(char), HostToDevice);
    dim3 grid_size(1);
    dim3 block_size((temp));
    Print <<< grid_size, temp >>> (string_GPU, my_string_length);
    cudaError_t final_error = cudaDeviceSynchronize(); //for synchronization e.g Hello_World then printf
    if (final_error == cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("%cKernel executed successfully with code: %d !%\n", NEW_LINE, final_error);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%cKernel executed with code error: %d !\n", NEW_LINE, final_error);
    }
    cudaFree(my_string_length);
    cudaFree(string_GPU);
    return 0;
}
```

I will be grateful for any help given.

Comment: Show the whole code to be able to help you.

Comment: I did it now. Greeting

Comment: Which libraries do you use?

Comment: stdio.h stdlib.h and build in basic project of cuda

Comment: There are various other things undefined, such as `Get_String_Length` and `HostToDevice`.

Comment: It doesnt matter, HostToDevice is just a my own shorter #define to cudaMemcpyHostToDevice

Comment: You should provide a code that other people can compile and run without having to guess at what things are.  So it does matter.  See item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ohh sorry for your inconvenience. I will remember about it ! Forgive me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that you are expecting that the thread or warp execution order has some predictable order.  Actually, it does not.  Your usage of `__syncthreads()` doesn't fix or address this issue.

If you want the warps to execute in a predictable order (not recommended) you would need to impose that order yourself.  Here is an example that demonstrates that for this very simple code.  It is not extensible without modification to larger strings, and this method will completely break down if you introduce more than 1 threadblock.

```
$ cat t1543.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__global__ void Print(const char* const __string, const size_t* const loop_repeat)
{
    int id_x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int warp_ID = threadIdx.x>>5;
    while (id_x < static_cast<int>(*loop_repeat))
    {
        if (warp_ID == 0)
          printf("%c", __string[id_x]);
        __syncthreads();
        if (warp_ID == 1)
          printf("%c", __string[id_x]);
        __syncthreads();
        id_x += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* my_string = "My temporary string is printed via GPU!";
    size_t temp;
    temp = 40;    //get the string length
    //GPU MEMORY ALLOCATION
    size_t* my_string_length;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&my_string_length, sizeof(size_t));
    //COPY VALUE FROM CPU(RAM) TO GPU
    cudaMemcpy(my_string_length, &temp, sizeof(size_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    char* string_GPU;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&string_GPU, (temp) * sizeof(char));
    //COPY VALUE FROM CPU(RAM) TO GPU
    cudaMemcpy(string_GPU, my_string, (temp) * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 grid_size(1);
    dim3 block_size((temp));
    Print <<< grid_size, temp >>> (string_GPU, my_string_length);
    cudaError_t final_error = cudaDeviceSynchronize(); //for synchronization e.g Hello_World then printf
    if (final_error == cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("\nKernel executed successfully with code: %d !%\n", final_error);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nKernel executed with code error: %d !\n", final_error);
    }
    cudaFree(my_string_length);
    cudaFree(string_GPU);
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1543 t1543.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1543
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
My temporary string is printed via GPU!
Kernel executed successfully with code: 0 !%
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that I'm not suggesting the above is good coding style.  It's provided for understanding of the issue.  Even this code is relying on the idea that the threads within a warp will call the `printf` function in a predictable order, which is not guaranteed by the CUDA programming model.  So the code is really still broken.

Comment: Thanks Robert ! I know that the threads are executing in unpredictable order, but I wondered is it possible to get thread execute order as I want. Greetings !

Answer (score 1):

This happened because **The multiprocessor creates, manages, schedules, and executes threads in groups of 32 parallel threads called warps** as you can see in [CUDA Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture), so the first 32 threads covers "My temporary string is printed v" and the remaining part covers "ia GPU!". It seems that the kernel put the latter wrap before the first one in execution order.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am so grateful !